# Google chrome javascript append doesn't add all nodes

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, videojs-transcript, interactive-transcript

Hello I have a simple Javascript code to append a video transcription into a div using `Video.js` and `videojs-transcript`. It works fine in Firefox but in Google Chrome when the transcription is too long it appends less than half of it. Also when I refresh it stops every time in different node.

A simple test code to produce the bug:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://walsh9.github.io/videojs-transcript/dist/videojs-transcript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <source src="https://pvclouddev.blob.core.windows.net/filescontainer/15TestLarge_1587760757304.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <track kind="captions" src="https://pvclouddev.blob.core.windows.net/filescontainer/790d31e9-d38d-48f4-87d5-9e9959acc39a.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default>
    </video>
    <div id="transcript"></div>
    <script>
        var video = videojs('video').ready(function(){
          // Set up any options.
          var options = {
            showTitle: false,
            showTrackSelector: false,
          };

          // Initialize the plugin.
          var transcript = this.transcript(options);

          // Then attach the widget to the page.
          var transcriptContainer = document.querySelector('#transcript');
          transcriptContainer.appendChild(transcript.el()); 
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Edit: In the `videojs-transcript` file when I try to `alert(cues.length)` in `createTranscriptBody` function it shows much less than what I got in Firefox.

Edit 2: I found out that the problem is with the method `createTranscriptBody` in `videojs-transcript.js`. It starts adding cues to the div before the vtt file is totally loaded. Is there any way to make it wait for the vtt to get fully loaded without using the timeout?

Comment: there are lots of errors in the captions file. many cues have start times before previous cues which is invalid, as are times like `00:03:60.013`. can you replicate with a valid file?

Comment: @misterben i generated a new valide vtt file and edited the test code but the same problem .

Comment: Which repository and version are you using for videojs-transcript. Please see my SO question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69697954/which-videojs-transcript-and-repo-version-should-be-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing the videoJs version from 4.12 to 7.6.6 and this is the js link :
https://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js