# What is the latest working version of videojs-transcript?

Tags: video, video.js, videojs-transcript

The "working sample" for videojs-transcript, whose link is on the [author's Github page](https://github.com/walsh9/videojs-transcript) uses an old version, 0.7.1, from 2014. The master branch is 3 versions ahead at 0.8.1, from 2017. When I attempt to run 0.8.1, it fails:

"Uncaught TypeError: my._options is undefined" in videojs-transcript.js:379:5"

The only way that I could get something working was to download the files used by the sample from the author's github.io page.

The author did not create an npm package. But I noticed that there are two npm packages for this component:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-transcript-ac
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@packt/videojs-transcript

I couldn't find a corresponding code repository for videojs-transcript-acvideojs-transcript-ac. But there is a bitbucket repo for @packt/videojs-transcript.

The original author's (walsh9) working sample is from 2014. I noticed that there are much more recent stackoverflow Q&A for videojs-transcript, even a couple from this year.

What and where is the latest working version for this package? Is there a fix to the author's latest 0.8.1 version available? (There hasn't been any activity on https://github.com/walsh9/videojs-transcript since 2017)

Comment: There's not really an authoritative answer to this, but this fork looks reasonably up to date https://github.com/tomByrer/videojs-transcript-click.

Comment: tomBryer's fork is missing the source files from his repo. It looked at first like he took the latest 0.8.1 distribution file from walsh9's repo and changed it. But studying this further, I see that he is just using the old 0.7.1 distribution file.